# Getting incompatible types errors

Tags: java, data-mining, decision-tree

Hello fellow programmers. I am in the process of learning Java as a potential career path, but I am now doing it as a hobby (for the lack of a better word); even though I do not consider myself a beginner, I am having issues with what I thought were simple errors that for some reason I can't figure out.

Here is the code I am following:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class ID3
{

        int []array = new int[values.size()];
        for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
            String symbol = (String)values.elementAt(i);
            array = domains[attribute].indexOf(symbol);//Type Error
        }
        values = null;
        return array;
    }

    public void decomposeNode(TreeNode node) {
        double bestEntropy=0;
        boolean selected=false;
        int selectedAttribute=0;
        int numdata = node.data.size();
        int numinputattributes = numAttributes-1;
        node.entropy = calculateEntropy(node.data);
        if (node.entropy == 0) return;

        for (int i=0; i< numinputattributes; i++) {
            int numvalues = domains.size(); //Cannot resolve method (?)
            if ( alreadyUsedToDecompose(node, i) ) continue;
            double averageentropy = 0;
            for (int j=0; j< numvalues; j++) {
                Vector subset = getSubset(node.data, i, j);
                if (subset.size() == 0) continue;
                double subentropy = calculateEntropy(subset);
                averageentropy += subentropy *
                        subset.size();
            }




        domains = new Vector[numAttributes];
    for (int i=0; i < numAttributes; i++) domains = new Vector();//TYPE ERROR
        attributeNames = new String[numAttributes];
        for (int i=0; i < numAttributes; i++) {
            attributeNames = tokenizer.nextToken(); //TYPE ERROR
        }

        .....

            DataPoint point = new DataPoint(numAttributes);

            for (int i=0; i < numAttributes; i++) {

                point.attributes = getSymbolValue(i, tokenizer.nextToken()//TYPE ERROR
                );
            }
            root.data.addElement(point);
        }
        bin.close();
        return 1;
    }


        int numvalues = node.children.length;
        for (int i=0; i < numvalues; i++) {
            System.out.println(tab + "if( " +
                    attributeNames[node.decompositionAttribute] + " == \"" +
                    domains[node.decompositionAttribute].elementAt(i)
                    + "\") {" );
            printTree(node.children, tab + "\t"); //Incompatible types
            if (i != numvalues-1) System.out.print(tab + "} else ");
            else System.out.println(tab + "}");
        }
    }

    public void createDecisionTree() {
       .....
    }
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error:(368, 57) java: incompatible types: java.util.Vector cannot be converted to java.util.Vector[]
Error:(374, 49) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.lang.String[]
Error:(410, 50) java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]
Error:(449, 71) java: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
Error:(473, 27) java: incompatible types: ID3.TreeNode[] cannot be converted to ID3.TreeNode
```

Very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Since you've given us a lot of code, it's too hard to scan through it and try to figure out where the errors are.  Please edit your question and indicate what lines the errors are happening on (don't just give us the line number, that isn't helpful).  Even better: start whittling your code down to narrow down where the error is occurring, and post a smaller example.

Comment: An error would come up if you declare something like `Vector[] v; String[] s`;  Here, `v` is an _array_ of vectors (so it's kind of like a 2-dimensional array), and `s` is an _array_ of strings.  If you try to assign a single `Vector` into `v`, or a single `String` into `s`, it will fail because the compiler is expecting an array, not a single value.

Comment: I took the working code out of the way and just left the chunks where the errors are present. Also left a comment next the corresponding lines to make it easier.

Comment: You cut out too much.  You're getting errors involving `domains`, but you eliminated the part where `domains` is declared.  Fortunately SO lets me see the previous version.

Comment: `array = domains[attribute].indexOf(symbol);`: `indexOf` returns an `int`, but `array` is an array of `int`.  You can't do the assignment, because the types are mismatched.  What did you think it would do?  `domains.size()`: `domains` is an array, and arrays don't have `size` methods.

Comment: `printTree(node.children, tab + "\t");`: `printTree` needs a `TreeNode` as a parameter, but you're trying to pass the entire array of `TreeNodes` to it.  Thus the "incompatible types".

Comment: There is a common theme here: you're using entire arrays where you need to use single elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` symbols should only be used for *arrays*.

```
String[] array = "error";
```

Does not compile, because the type on the left is an *array* of vectors, while on the right there is a *single* string only.